# Changing the color of only one directory in ls

Tags: ls, colors

Is there a way to change the color of only one of the listed directories in the `ls` command? I have researched the `LS_COLORS` variable, but this doesn't solve the issue because you cannot list specific files or directories in the `LS_COLORS` variable.

I have been producing a bash script to accomplish this, but so far it's proven extremely complicated. There must be an easier way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I understands it, you can only specify files that ends with a specific pattern, for example `*.jpg=01;31` to make jpg-files red. Then of course you can always trick it with something like this `*IMG_20150808_202948.jpg=01;31` :)

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with @nsg that you cannot do this, it seems that the [*documentation*](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#General-output-formatting) is lacking.  So you can read the source-code for `ls`, in [print_color_indicator](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c#n4348), in particular the place where it [checks file-suffix](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c#n4429), commenting

```
/* Check the file's suffix only if still classified as C_FILE.  */
```

So, no: you cannot fool it by making a directory-name ending with **`".jpg"`**.  You can only apply the suffixes to filenames (and see the code) the suffix need not begin with a **`"."`**.